# Running a loop on data set to check the change in accounts assigned to sales representatives

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a help on running a loop on my data set for the following:

The sales reps are assigned accounts every quarter. There are movements of the accounts as specified in the example below. I have to go through the data for each rep and capture the quarters in which rep moved out of the account or into the account.

For example, I need a way to capture that Rep 1 moved out of ABC in 2019-Q3 and back to ABC in 2019-Q4.

Data set:

[image: data]

Comment: Can you share what you have attempted so far? Especially any code

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: And ensure your sample data and desired results are formatted text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

Below is *a* possible solution using a [cross apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply) to fetch the related previous record (`prev`). Without a description or sample of your expected result it is hard to provide a final solution...

**Sample data**

```
declare @SalesRep table
(
    [Status]    nvarchar(10),
    [Quarter]   nvarchar(10),
    [RepDetail] nvarchar(10),
    [Account]   nvarchar(10)
);

insert into @SalesRep ([Status], [Quarter], [RepDetail], [Account]) values
('Active',  '2019-Q1',  'Rep 1',    'ABC'),
('Active',  '2019-Q1',  'Rep 2',    'ABC'),
('Active',  '2019-Q1',  'Rep 3',    'XYZ'),
('Active',  '2019-Q1',  'Rep 4',    'ABC'),
('Active',  '2019-Q2',  'Rep 1',    'ABC'),
('Active',  '2019-Q2',  'Rep 2',    'ABC'),
('Active',  '2019-Q2',  'Rep 3',    'ABC'),
('Active',  '2019-Q2',  'Rep 4',    'ABC'),
('Active',  '2019-Q3',  'Rep 1',    'XYZ'),
('Active',  '2019-Q3',  'Rep 2',    'ABC'),
('Inactive','2019-Q3',  'Rep 3',    null ),
('Active',  '2019-Q3',  'Rep 4',    'ABC'),
('Active',  '2019-Q4',  'Rep 1',    'ABC'),
('Active',  '2019-Q4',  'Rep 2',    'XYZ'),
('Active',  '2019-Q4',  'Rep 4',    'PQR');
```

**Solution**

```
select  sr1.[RepDetail] as 'Rep',
        prev.[Quarter]  as 'OldQuarter',
        prev.[Account]  as 'OldAccount',
        sr1.[Quarter]   as 'NewQuarter',
        sr1.[Account]   as 'NewAccount'
from @SalesRep sr1
cross apply (   select top 1 sr2.[Account], sr2.[Quarter]
                from @SalesRep sr2
                where sr2.[RepDetail] = sr1.[RepDetail]
                  and sr2.[Status] = 'Active'
                  and sr2.[Quarter] < sr1.[Quarter]
                order by sr2.[Quarter] desc ) prev
where sr1.[Account] <> prev.Account                     -- option 1: rep changes to another account
--where coalesce(sr1.[Account],'') <> prev.Account      -- option 2: same as 1, but also show rep going inactive
order by sr1.[RepDetail], sr1.[Quarter];
```

**Result**

```
Rep        OldQuarter OldAccount NewQuarter NewAccount
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Rep 1      2019-Q2    ABC        2019-Q3    XYZ
Rep 1      2019-Q3    XYZ        2019-Q4    ABC
Rep 2      2019-Q3    ABC        2019-Q4    XYZ
Rep 3      2019-Q1    XYZ        2019-Q2    ABC
Rep 3      2019-Q2    ABC        2019-Q3    NULL        --> only included if using option 2
Rep 4      2019-Q3    ABC        2019-Q4    PQR
```